# How to model the IBM quantum errors?

Tags: qiskit, error-correction, noise, kraus-representation, error-mitigation

I'm conducting a study of the quantum channel errors, and a question has arisen: Is it possible to model the errors of an IBM quantum computer with Kraus operators?